# How to get value of click event in meteor js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How to get the value of click event in **meteor Js**
For example i want **{{name}}** this value.Here is put my code it showing **undefined**in alert box.Please verify and suggest me.

```
client JS:
Template.client.events({
    'click .clientrow':function(e,t){

         console.log("You Select Client Row ");
         e.preventDefault();
         alert($(e.target).closest('tr').data('_id'));

    }
});
template:
<template name="client">
<tbody>
    {{#each clientList}}
    <tr class="clientrow">
       <td data-id="{{_id}}">{{cid}}</td>
       <td>{{mrno}}</td>
       <td>{{client}}</td>
       <td>{{formatDate rdate}}</td>
       <td>{{referredby}}</td>
       <td>{{clinecian}}</td>
       <td>{{serviece}}</td>
       <td>{{episode}}</td>
       <td>{{actions}}</td>
    </tr>
     {{/each}}              
  </tbody>
</template>
```

Comment: What do you mean by value? You can access the whole event in callback and pick the data you need.

Comment: I am displaying the user input values in table getting from collection ok it is working but i want in a table row if we click user name in a table row show that name in alert box@ Hubert OG

Comment: Above my code is placed please verify and where i did a mistake tell me@Hubert OG

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily access the element that was clicked:

```
'click .something': function(e, t) {
  $(e.target);
}
```

Now, if you want the data stored in a row that was clicked, you can easily make it accessible with `data` HTML parameters

```
{{#each items}}
  <tr data-name="{{name}}" data-id="{{_id}}">...</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Afterwards, extract it from the row:

```
'click .something': function(e, t) {
  alert($(e.target).closest('tr').data('name'));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There is a an easier and cleaner approach. Inside the event handler `this` refers to the Handlebars template context, which is actually your `clientList` object. So you could do something like:

```
Template.client.events({
'click .clientrow':function(e,t){

     console.log("You Select Client Row " + this.client);
     alert(this.mrno + ' ' + this.client);

}
});
```